# Cannot configure Router in Express NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I have the next server file:

```
'use strict'

const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

const index = require('./routes/index');
const chat = require('./routes/chat');

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/chat', chat);

const port = process.env.API_PORT || 8989;
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

and the next two routes `index.js` and `chat.js` in `./routes` dir:

```
// ./routes/index.js

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/')
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.json('Hello on the Homepage!');
    });

module.exports = router;



// ./routes/chat.js

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/chat')
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.json('Hello on the Chatpage!');
    });

module.exports = router;
```

The first one `index.js` loads normaly by standart port `localhost:8989/`, but when I what to get the second route by `localhost:8989/chat` - I always receive `error` - `Cannot GET /chat`...

What is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what about `localhost:8989/chat/chat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `server.js`

```
const index = require('./routes/index');
const chat = require('./routes/chat');


app.use('/chat', chat); // when path is :/chat/bla/foo
app.use('/', index);
```

In `./routes/index.js`

```
router.route('/')
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.json('Hello on the Homepage!');
    });
```

In `./routes/chat.js`

```
// It is already in `:/chat`. There we need to map rest part of URL.
router.route('/')  
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.json('Hello on the Chatpage!');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// ./routes/chat.js

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/')
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.json('Hello on the Chatpage!');
    });

module.exports = router;
```

you can use this